# Do Cloudfront Regional Edge Caches Synchronise Objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

AWS is fairly clear about how objects are delivered through CloudFront as illustrated (and explained) in their [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/HowCloudFrontWorks.html).

Furthermore, I understand that **Edge Locations** do NOT synchronise data between each edge node (I can't remember where I read this but my tests have confirmed this is the case). However, what is not clear is whether CloudFront will synchronise cached data between **Regional Edge Locations**. Can anyone shed any further light on this?

For reference:
[image: AWS CloudFront]

Comment: Yeah, you are right it will not replicate data on the regional edge cache, In case of a cache miss from the edge cache, CloudFront will forward that request to its regional cache. Andi if it's not in its regional cache it will be a cache miss and a request will go to origin. I suppose that's when Origin shield comes in handy, with Origin Shield requests from all regional caches go through a single Origin Shield regional cache which then means the origin will only need to serve 1 request. Also, Origin Sheild queued your requests if its see same requests are invoked by all the cache regions.

Comment: @user15558255 - I completely forgot about Origin Shield! That may solve my issue actually... The reason for my question is that I have a Lambda Edge function that dynamically updates certain responses from the Origin and then returns these to the user (through the cache). These updates can take a second or two and therefore I want to ensure that once they are done for each file, they are cached everywhere so someone from each region doesn't have to wait 1-2 seconds for the function to run. I believe Origin Shield will provide this

Comment: Yeah definitely looks like a valid use case for using Origin Shield

Comment: @user15558255 - feel free to post up an answer so I can accept it. This will make it easier for others to find the answer in the future, and will reward you for your knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct; CloudFront will not replicate your cache throughout regional edge nodes.

However, if you are looking for something to act as a cache in front of your origin (e.g. to cache Lambda Edge responses), you can enable [Origin Shield](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/origin-shield.html).

The benefits of Origin Shield are:

- Better cache hit ratio
- Reduced origin load
- Better network performance

See here:
[image: Origin Shield]